# treeview - uso del enter

Tags: c#

estoy armando un treeview desde una tabla SQL. En C# Lo que quiero hacer ahora, es usar el ENTER en lugar del doble click para que en el nodo (que es dinámico porque esta armado desde una tabla) llame a un formulario.

Yo en el evento `NodeMouseDoubleClick` tengo programada la accion, pero no encuentro un evento `NodeEnter` , ni `NodeKeyPress`.

Alguien puede ayudarme como hay que hacerlo.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ya lo resolvi: lo dejo por si sirve.

 private void arbolMenu_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != arbolMenu.SelectedNode)
            {
                // if the Enter key was pressed
                if ((char)Keys.Return == e.KeyChar)
                {
                    
                    llamaraccion();

                }

Comment: Si esa es la solucion, por favor ponla como solucion y despues aceptala.